# ATI card (Radeon HD 5850) forced screensaver settings

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, screensaver

I just installed an ATI graphics (Radeon HD 5850) to my desktop swapping my nVidia GTS250. I noticed it turns off the output if idle for 2 minutes, Even if I was running a video! unless the mouse/keyboard do anything, It will not stay on.

Screensaver settings: none
Power settings: none
Before installing the official drivers from AMD: Yes
After that: STILL yes

I tried anything. And now I am turning for you to help. Save e from this frustration please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use Caffeine..on you Ubuntu. Read more from [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/2-ways-to-temporarily-disable.html).

Comment: The screen turnoffs are not done because of the screensaver settings in ubuntu settings nor power options. For some reason they only appear with this graphics card. Furthermore if left for 30-40 minutes it would not even recover from the screen off unless I hard reset the box!

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. But I'm sure it will be more likely that you get your problem solved if you explain the situation more clearly.